# Non-Palindromic Polyglot Boggle

Tags: code-challenge, sequence, palindrome, polyglot, boggle

### Introduction

The number 101 is a palindrome, since it reads the same backwards and forwards. The number 105 is not. However, 105 in base eight is written as 151, which *is* palindromic. On the other hand, 103 is not a palindrome in *any* base from 2 to 101. Hence, 103 is **[strictly non-palindromic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strictly_non-palindromic_number)**.

The precise definition is: A nonnegative integer *n* is strictly non-palindromic if it is not a palindrome in any base between 2 and n-2, inclusive.

The first few strictly non-palindromic numbers are `0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 6, 11, 19, 47, 53, 79, 103, 137, 139, 149, 163, 167, 179, 223, 263, 269...` ([A016038](https://oeis.org/A016038))

Write a full program that takes a number *x* from STDIN and prints the *x*th strictly non-palindromic number. For example, the input `5` would produce the output `4`.

### Challenge

The challenge is to write multiple (one or more) programs, each solving this task in a different language.

Then, you must put all of the programs in a rectangular grid of characters. The programs can be accessed Boggle-style. That is, go from one character to a neighboring character (including diagonally), never using the same character more than once.

For example, the following grid:

```
abc
bdc
```

includes the words `abc`, `ccd`, `bbad`, and `bcdb`, but not `ac`, `bdd`, `bcb`, or `cbbc`.

Each program must be found in the grid using these rules. However, you may use the same character in multiple programs.

### Score

Your score is the number of characters in the grid, divided by the number of programs. Lowest score wins!

### Rules

- Two languages are considered different if they usually go by different names, ignoring version numbers. For example, C and C++ are different, but Python 2 and Python 3 are the same.
- The characters in the grid must all be from printable ASCII, i.e., from  to `~`, code points `20` through `FE`.
- Each program must consist only of printable ASCII, plus newlines. When inserting a program into the grid, replace each newline with a space.

  - A space in the grid may represent a space in one program and a newline in another.
- The grid must be a rectangle.
- Not every character needs to be used in a program.

Comment: Aren't single digit numbers palindromic? They read the same backwards and forwards.

Comment: @RetoKoradi Correct. That's why we only consider bases less than `n-1`, so there will always be at least two digits.

Answer (score 10):

## 19x2 = 38, 2 programs, Score: <s>26</s> <s>19.5</s> 19

Here is the board:

```
-:\~{.,><1\b_W%}}g}
1Wq{)_2W{$ase.=,do*
```

This contains the following programs:

## CJam (27 bytes)

```
Wq~{{)_,2>W<{1$\b_W%=},}g}*
```

[Test it here.](http://cjam.aditsu.net/#code=Wq~%7B%7B)_%2C2%3EW%3C%7B1%24%5Cb_W%25%3D%7D%2C%7Dg%7D*&input=10)

These are the characters of the board used for this code:

```
   ~{ ,><1\b_W%}}g}
 Wq{)_2W{$    =,  *
```

## GolfScript (34 bytes)

```
-1:W\~{{).,2>W<{1$\base.W%=},}do}*
```

[Test it here.](http://golfscript.apphb.com/?c=OyIxMCIKCi0xOldcfnt7KS4sMj5XPHsxJFxiYXNlLlclPX0sfWRvfSo%3D)

These are the characters of the board used for this code:

```
-:\~{.,><1\b W%}} }
1W {) 2W{$ase.=,do*
```